# Semantic error with scope/namespace with return function in python

Tags: python, scope, return, nested-function

While trying to understand return and scope I tried writing the function below but found that it only returns the value of x evaluated as `x += 20`

```
 def this_is_return(x):
    """
    takes as input x and passes it to a second function which operates 
    on it returns to first function which operates on it more before 
    returning value to console
    """
     def second_function(x):
         x *= 2
         print(x)
         return x
     second_function(x)
     x += 20
     return x
```

When written as below the function works as expected.  But I am really interested in what I am not understanding about the limits of return with respect to the initial value x.  My block diagramming skills are nebulous.

```
 def this_is_return(x):
    """
    takes as input x and passes it to a second function, which 
    operates on it and assigns it to c, returns c to
    function assigned to d; first function then operates on it more 
    before returning value to console
    """
    def second_function(x):
        c = x * 2
        print(c)
        return c
    d = second_function(x)
    x = d + 20
    return x
```

Comment: In the first example you call second_function but do not do anything with its return.

Comment: `x` is a local variable everywhere, and don't relate to each other at all. You simply discard the value returned by `second_function`, and then `x` in the caller's scope is the local `x` that hasn't been touched...

Comment: Ok, that makes sense.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, the heart of the problem is that a reasonable person might expert that `x *= 2` doubles the value of `x`.  It does, but the doubling doesn't persist:

```
>>> def second_function(x):
...          x *= 2
...          print(x)
...          return x
... 
>>> x = 10 ; second_function(x)
20
20
>>> x
10
```

Let's take this step by step:

1. `def second_function(x):`

   `x` points to the data that was passed in.
2. `x *= 2`

   The data that was passed in was multiplied by two and, locally, `x` points to a new number that is double the old number.  The memory location that contains the old number is unaffected.

   Integers are immutable.  They cannot be changed "in-place."
3. `print(x); return x`

   The local `x` is printed and returned.

In the first_function, though, `x` is still pointing to the original data.  The original data was never changed.

In sum, `x *= 2` does not change the data in-place.  It causes `x` to point to new number.  Other variables which point to the old data are unaffected.

#### Alternate version using mutable variables

Instead of passing an integer, let's pass in a list:

```
>>> def third_function(x):
...     x[0] *= 2
...     print(x)
... 
>>> x = [10]; third_function(x)
[20]
>>> x
[20]
```

As you can see, the change to the list `x` persists.  Lists are mutable.

Comment: Thank you for the step by step!